# Ordered list with variable element count as a feature for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I have a list with 0 - N elements that I'd like to use as a feature, where each element is an integer.

List Example:
[5, 2, 6, 4]

The list is ordered since the order represents set of actions.

If I was to complicate this such that each item in the list represented not only an integer put a tuple that represents time and action.

List Example:
[(5, 10), (2, 6), (6, 4), (4, 0)]

How would this be represented as a feature?

Comment: Can't you just make one column for time and one column for action ?

Comment: @ClementLombard, oh yeah, thanks for that, but how would I use the list itself as a feature?